# Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, python, django, cross-domain

I have a Vue.js frontend project, which start at the 8080 port. I access the site by: http://localhost:8080/register

and I use the Python/Django write the backend site. using Django-Rest-Framework provide the APIs. My backend APIs server is start as: http://0.0.0.0:8001/

But when I register( access the api ), I get bellow Access-Control-Allow-Origin error:

> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

In my Python backend project `settings.py` code are:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '8cyiv%(rkpv33s_(n8x_5&+6-9&s!ddc!0)98la3=9(y8=k$4u'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'corsheaders', 

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_docs',  # API docs
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    'wx_numbers',
    'users_management',

]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',   # corsheaders

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X_FILENAME',
    'accept-encoding',
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (

    'http://localhost:8080',
    'http://localhost:8081',
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:8888',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wx_backup.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wx_backup.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users_management.User"

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'wx_backup',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'abcdefghij',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-cn'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

You see I use the [`corsheaders`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) as the CORS solution, I also configured the `'http://localhost:8080'` in its `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`. Why I still get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the white list like bellow should work:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (

    'localhost:8080',
    'localhost:8081',
    'localhost',
    'localhost:8888',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (

    'localhost:8080',
    'localhost:8081',
    'localhost',
    'localhost:8888',
)
```

**no http://**